# Passing data from one activity fragment to a different activity fragement

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have been searching everywhere but can't seem to find a working example of how to pass a fragment to a fragment that is NOT in the the same activity. Could someone provide me with a great example please?

Comment: Use `Bundle` and use `setArguments(bundle)` for passing data between fragments.

Comment: See ans of "sony", please search before posting, Totally agree with his view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass data from one fragment  activity to another fragment activity.

`Actvity 1 Fragment :`

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("message", data); 
    startActivity(intent);
```

In  second activity fragment retrieve in this manner:

```
    SecondActivity activity = (SecondActivity) getActivity();
    String data= activity.getIntent().getExtras().getString("message");
```

Answer (score -2):

You haven't searched anywhere. These two links [official site](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) and [this](http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/09/25/inter-fragment-communication/). describes how to pass data between fragments. these are the first, two results of a simple google search and this is not a place to come and get the code you want.